# "Missing $ inserted" error while using Diagrams package

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I'm trying to create a commutative diagram using Paul Taylor's Diagrams package, but when I compile I get a "Missing $ inserted" error. Everything compiles fine if I comment out the diagram, so I know I haven't missed a $ somewhere else. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm, amsmath, calc, cite, diagrams, fullpage, latexsym, tikz}

\newcommand{\id}{\text{id}}

\begin{document}

\begin{diagram}
A*B & \lTo^{i} & B\\
\uTo^{i} & \rdTo^{\phi} & \dTo^{1}\\
A & \rTo_{\id_A} & A
\end{diagram}

\end{document}
```

The compiler is pointing to an error on the first line of the body of the diagram, but Diagrams automatically puts everything in math mode.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Zoxume: The name of the package is "diagrams" (it is plural). It can be found on CTAN or through Paul Taylor's website: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/diagrams or http://www.paultaylor.eu/diagrams/

Comment: Can’t reproduce. I downloaded the package [here](http://www.paultaylor.eu/diagrams/) and I got no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error. If you do not manage to get it working, you might want to get the (almost) same result by:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\id}{\text{id}}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{%
    commutative diagrams/.cd,
    arrow style=tikz,
    diagrams={>=latex}}
\tikzcdset{every label/.append style = {font = \small}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large,row sep=huge]
    A*B\arrow{dr}[sloped,pos=.45]{\phi} & B\arrow{l}[swap]{i}\arrow{d}[swap]{1} \\
    A\arrow{u}{i} \arrow{r}[swap]{\id_A} & A
\end{tikzcd}
\]  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave up trying to fix the issue and just used tikz-cd, as per your suggestion

Comment: @Bey You are welcome. I have added a lot of fixes in order to emulate your case. Of course, you could reduce that code here a lot. (`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A*B\arrow{dr}{\phi} & B\arrow{l}[swap]{i}\arrow{d}{1} \\
A\arrow{u}{i} \arrow{r}[swap]{\mathrm{id}_A} & A
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}`)